# Remove merge commit and revert merge completely from branch

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I have recently started working on git.
Here is the issue, it might be a bit confusing but I will try my best to describe my issue:

We are a group of developers , a master branch was created. We all created custom branches from it for the feature we are going to build separately. Lets say master is at "A" point. Couple of changes have been merged to master now.

One day I mistakenly merged my branch to master and pushed to remote then I realised that I made a mistake so I reverted that merge from master branch. I thought everything is fine. Now few more commits were done on top of my doing by somebody else.

Now the first issue is :

1) If I see master branch log, it is flooded with my commit history due to the merge I did, along with a revert merge.

2) If somebody else is trying to merge their changes to master they are getting allot of merge conflicts thats due to my "merge" and "merge revert" with master branch. At the time of their merge Git probably is first trying to align my merged changes with that other person's change and then it will revert my change. And the same thing will happen for other people as well who will merge their branch into master who have checked out master branch from point A.

Hope I didn't made it confusing.

Is it possible to remove my branch "merge" and "revert merge" completely from master ?

Comment: You didn't want `git revert`, that creates a new commit that reverts the changes.  You wanted a complete reset of the history to before the oops.  `git checkout master; git reset --hard before_the_oops; git push --force`.  Git doesn't make this particularly convenient to do, for good reason, but it does make it possible, also for good reason.  Mistakes like this are one of the reasons to force-push.  Be sure everybody else knows to refetch.

Comment: but that would wipe out the changes done by somebody else after_the_oops also.
I just now googled that by running "git rebase -p --onto OOPS^ OOPSREVERT" would wipe out the  mistake I did but only for my local . It is exactly what I wanted but It shows :
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 68 different commits each, respectively.

Now how do I push this state of master branch to remote ?

Comment: No, it wouldn't.  It would make them rebase their work on the corrected history, though, and it's the only way to remove your mistake completely from master as asked.

Comment: what i think is "git reset --hard before_the_oops" would reset the branch to a commit just before my commit. But what about the commits which had gone to master after my commit ? 

the issue got actually solved using :
"git rebase -p --onto OOPS^ OOPSREVERT" then "git push -f"

But thanks @jthill for taking out time to suggest an answer :)